# How can I save the data in the treeview to the .json structure in c#?

Tags: c#, json, winforms, treeview

Here are the codes I wrote and the .json file I saved

```
 private void WriteTreeViewToJson(TreeView treeView, string filePath)
 {
     if (treeView.Nodes.Count == 0) return;

     var rootNode = TraverseNodes(treeView.Nodes);

     var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(rootNode, Formatting.Indented);

     File.WriteAllText(filePath, json);
 }

 private TreeNodeData TraverseNodes(TreeNodeCollection nodes)
 {
     var nodeList = new List<TreeNodeData>();

     foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
     {
        var newNode = new TreeNodeData
        {                    
            symbol = Convert.ToString(GetNodeValue<string>(node.Nodes, "symbol")),
            ask = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "ask")),
            bid = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "bid")),
            last = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "last")),
            low = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "low")),
            high = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "high")),
            open = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "open")),
            volume = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "volume")),
            volumeQuote = Convert.ToDouble(GetNodeValue<double>(node.Nodes, "volumeQuote")),
            timestamp = Convert.ToDateTime(GetNodeValue<DateTime>(node.Nodes, "timestamp")),
            Nodes = TraverseNodes(node.Nodes)?.Nodes
                
         };

            // Alt düğümlerdeki değişkenleri okuma
        foreach (TreeNode subNode in node.Nodes)
        {
            var property = typeof(TreeNodeData).GetProperty(subNode.Name);
            if (property != null)
            {
                var value = Convert.ChangeType(subNode.Text, property.PropertyType);
                property.SetValue(newNode, value);                   
             }
         }
            nodeList.Add(newNode);
     }
        return new TreeNodeData { Nodes = nodeList };
 }

private T? GetNodeValue<T>(TreeNodeCollection nodes, string propertyName)
{
     foreach (TreeNode node in nodes)
     {
         if (node.Name == propertyName)
         {
             if (typeof(T).IsValueType)
             {
                 try
                 {
                     return (T)Convert.ChangeType(node.Nodes[0].Text, typeof(T));
                 }
                    catch (InvalidCastException)
                    {
                        return default;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (node.Nodes.Count > 0)
                    {
                        var childNode = node.Nodes[3];
                        return (T)Convert.ChangeType(childNode.Text, typeof(T));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return default;
                    }
                }
            }

            T? value = GetNodeValue<T>(node.Nodes, propertyName);
            if (value != null)
                return value;
        }

        return default;
  }
```

When I save the file it should look like this:

```
[
  {
    "symbol":"LRCBTC",
    "ask":"0.000007415",
    "bid":"0.000007323",
    "last":"0.000007313",
    "low":"0.000007276",
    "high":"0.000007560",
    "open":"0.000007493",
    "volume":"4486",
    "volumeQuote":"0.033301087",
    "timestamp":"2023-07-10T07:32:44.744Z"
  }
]
```

but it looks like this

```
[
  {
  "symbol":null,
  "ask":null,
  "bid":null,
  "last":null,
  "low":null,
  "high":null,
  "open":null,
  "volume":null,
  "volumeQuote":null,
  "timestamp":null,
  "Nodes":[
     {
        "symbol":null,
        "ask":null,
        "bid":null,
        "last":null,
        "low":null,
        "high":null,
        "open":null,
        "volume":null,
        "volumeQuote":null,
        "timestamp":null,
        "Nodes":[
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           },
           {
              "symbol":null,
              "ask":null,
              "bid":null,
              "last":null,
              "low":null,
              "high":null,
              "open":null,
              "volume":null,
              "volumeQuote":null,
              "timestamp":null,
              "Nodes":[
                 
              ]
           }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: you doing recursive . if you need to make Nodes with attribute [JsonIgnore] in class